# How can I run oink in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memory-management, heroku, oink

I'm having a problem running the oink gem on my app in Heroku. I've included it in my gemfile and gemfile.lock, uploaded those, and it installs. It even creates the oink.log (which I have no way of viewing, unfortunately). When I run

`heroku run bundle exec oink --threshold=0 log/* --app my_app`

I get

> Running bundle exec oink --threshold=0
>   log/delayed_job.log log/development.log log/oink.log log/production.log log/test.log attached to terminal... up, run.3
>   /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/oink-0.9.3/bin/../lib/oink/cli.rb:88:in get_file_listing':
>   Could not find "log/delayed_job.log" (RuntimeError)
>   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/oink-0.9.3/bin/../lib/oink/cli.rb:86:ineach'
>   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/oink-0.9.3/bin/../lib/oink/cli.rb:86:in get_file_listing'
>   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/oink-0.9.3/bin/../lib/oink/cli.rb:59:inprocess'
>   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/oink-0.9.3/bin/oink:4
>   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bin/oink:19:in 'load'
>   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bin/oink:19

I've tried running each of the individual files, too, and get the same result. This command runs fine on my local machine.

In my production.rb file, I have

> config.logger = Hodel3000CompliantLogger.new(config.paths.log.first)
>   config.middleware.use( Oink::Middleware )

as configuration.

Can you enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong here? My understanding is that the logs are read only, but I don't know if that means they're only accessible through the `heroku logs` command. If there's a way I can see the oink.log file, too--knowing how to do that is also appreciated, or knowing how to see it in the actual Heroku log using `heroku logs`.

UPDATE: The configuration for oink shown above allows the commands to be run successfully on my localhost.

Thanks!

-Andrew

Comment: please format your question more properly

Comment: Anyone have responses to this? I am facing the same problem- @aferris did you ever solve it?

Comment: I contacted Heroku directly and they couldn't solve the issue for me. I haven't looked further into it, either, as it would just help with debugging, and so isn't completely necessary, but is instead a nice to have.