# Rails oink with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

This question has been asked before but no answer seems to work for me. I will break the problem down into its 3 components:

1) I receive a Heroku R14 memory (memory quota exceeded) occasionally (i.e. the site has been up 2 days on Heroku and I got this error twice for a period of about 10-15 mn [I was too emotional to count the time precisely]).

2) I installed the oink gem as advised by Heroku.

3) Oink definitely logs, as I get messages to that effect in heroku logs and in Webrick when I work locally. However, I am unable to access the logging summary that shows which functions exceed a memory threshold.

The only line that returns a result (but a wrong one) is :

```
oink --threshold=0 logfile_for_oink
```

But it returns empty lines as follows:

```
---- MEMORY THRESHOLD ----
THRESHOLD: 0 MB

-- SUMMARY --
Worst Requests:

Worst Actions:

Aggregated Totals:
```

Every other attempt - often copying advice already on StackOverflow - returns errors.

I will list the different attempts I have made (so no-one posts a suggestion I may have already tried) after this.

heroku run bundle exec oink --threshold=75 log/*

This line returns the following error:

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/oink-0.10.1/lib/oink/cli.rb:88:in `block in get_file_listing': Could not find "log/development.log" (RuntimeError)

Every variation on this, such as log/production.rb or /log/* or what have you has failed.

I also tried the advice on the following links to no avail:

[Using oink gem with heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986144/using-oink-gem-with-heroku)

[oink logs command not working on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359552/oink-logs-command-not-working-on-heroku)

[oink logs command not working on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359552/oink-logs-command-not-working-on-heroku)

[How can I run oink in heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568139/how-can-i-run-oink-in-heroku)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku prepends the log file with an additional timestamp so oink can't read it. You can use a regex though to fix it.

http://arches.io/2013/07/understand-memory-usage-on-heroku-rails-app-using-oink/